# How to set TRANSFORMER_KEY argument in my Java client code?

Tags: html, web-services, export, jasperserver

I am working jasperserver for past few days. I want to export the jasper report to HTML page using webservice(SOAP). If I run the client code I got the following exception:

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.LicenseException: No license provider found
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.LicenseManager.requireProvider(LicenseManager.java:94)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.LicenseManager.requireFeature(LicenseManager.java:112)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.fusion.FusionUtils.requireFusionFeature(FusionUtils.java:50)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.fusion.BaseHtmlHandler.getHtmlFragment(BaseHtmlHandler.java:48)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.writeGenericElement(HtmlExporter.java:1414)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$CellElementVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2595)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$CellElementVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2513)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplateGenericPrintElement.accept(JRTemplateGenericPrintElement.java:164)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2484)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2468)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.tabulator.ElementCell.accept(ElementCell.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportTable(HtmlExporter.java:583)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.writeLayers(HtmlExporter.java:1461)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2508)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2468)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.tabulator.LayeredCell.accept(LayeredCell.java:65)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportTable(HtmlExporter.java:583)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.writeLayers(HtmlExporter.java:1461)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2508)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter$TableVisitor.visit(HtmlExporter.java:2468)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.tabulator.LayeredCell.accept(LayeredCell.java:65)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportTable(HtmlExporter.java:583)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportPage(HtmlExporter.java:486)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportReportToWriter(HtmlExporter.java:378)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter.exportReport(HtmlExporter.java:236)
    at flying.JSClientTest.main(JSClientTest.java:87)
```

I just google this error and got a reference from jasper community. They said to pass an argument named `TRANSFORMER_KEY` having `net.sf.jasperreports.transformer.html` as value.

Ref links: 
    http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-server-license-issue-when-invoked-web-service

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-execute-reports-containing-fusion-charts-web-services

But I have no idea how to pass this argument in my client code.